# Cant move the screen if i swipe on the items in the grid - metro style application

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, html, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have just created a grid application using the template provided in Visual Studio 11.

If I swipe in the  area that does not have any content (area outside listview) the screen moves, as I expected, in the swipe direction.

My problem is, if the user swipes on the area which contain items in the list view, nothing will happen.

How can i make the swipe functionality similar on the entire screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked fine as i expected when i added some more `data-win-options` to the list view..

Here is my final data-win options

```
data-win-options="{selectionMode:'none',swipeBehavior:'none',tapBehaviour:'invoke'}"
```